# How does google determine use of word over time in Dictionary?

Tags: google-search

When we look for certain word in dictionary on google, it also shows us a graph like this at the bottom, which tells about use of searched word over time. How google determines its use? What reference does it use?

[image]

Comment: I think they analyse old documents like letters and books

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming or code you've written

Comment: @JohnConde still not closed

Answer (score 0):

> The **Google Ngram Viewer** or Google Books Ngram Viewer is an online
> search engine that **charts the frequencies of any set of search strings**
> using a yearly count of n-grams found in sources printed between 1500
> and 2019 in Google's text corpora in English, Chinese (simplified),
> French, German, Hebrew, Italian, Russian, or Spanish. The program can
> search for a word or a phrase, including misspellings or gibberish.The
> n-grams are matched with the text within the selected corpus,
> optionally using case-sensitive spelling (which compares the exact use
> of uppercase letters), and, if found in 40 or more books, are then
> **displayed as a graph**.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Ngram_Viewer

Refer: https://books.google.com/ngrams/info